# Getting data between two div or a tags in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on a scraping project in which there is some data between two different divs and two different a tags and we want to fetch everything in between them.

Sample problem 1:

```
<div id ="startID"></div>
<table>
    <tr>
        data
    </tr>
</table>

<p>Paragraph data</p>
<div id="endID"></div>
```

Expected outcome 1: basically it fetches everything in between those two div elements.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        data
    </tr>
</table>

<p>Paragraph data</p>
```

I know how to get the data inside a div tag but to get the data between two div tags is problematic.

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Is that information between the `div` start-end elements always a `table` and a `p`? What format should the result be? A table, a list, a dictionary, something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.next_sibling` to iteratively extract text from the `startID` tag until you find the `endID` tag.

```
startID = soup.find(id="startID")
endID = soup.find(id="endID")
data = []
for sibling in startID.next_siblings:
    if sibling == endID:
        break
    text = sibling.get_text(strip=True)
    if text:
        data.append(text)
```

output:

```
> data

['data', 'Paragraph data']
```

Comment: I'll run it once for my usecase and accept the answer.